# CSS selector for the last occurrence of a class on a page

Tags: css, prototypejs, css-selectors

Is there a CSS selector for the last occurrence of a class on a page?

Say i have this HTML

```
<dd>
    <span>
        <a class="required" id="forename">foo</a>
    </span>
</dd>
<dd>
    <span>
        <a class="required" id="surname">bar</a>
    </span>
</dd>
```

Is there a CSS selector that would return the `a` tag with the ID of surname. Something like `.required:last` maybe?

Will be using Prototype if that matters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Prototype:

```
var sel = $(document.body).select('a.required').toArray()
var last = sel[sel.length-1]
```

(alternately:  `var last = sel.last()`)

There may be an easier way.

Comment: according to this page (http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar) last-child should work with Prototype, is there a reason you havent used that method?

Comment: actually, `$(document.body).select('a.required').last()` works just fine!

Comment: Cool, I'm a little rusty on my Prototype.

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 has the :last-child selector, but not many browsers support it.

If you can use jquery, you can do:

```
$("a.required:last")
```

Comment: `:last-child` is a wrong answer; it will not let you select the last element matching a selector *on the page*, which is what the OP asked for. Indeed, using the OP's example HTML, `:last-child` will match both of the elements he wants to tell the difference between: http://jsfiddle.net/urx4sjo7/

Answer (score 0):

<s>`:last-of-type` can work in some circumstances (when all `.required` elements have a common parent), but support is [spotty](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-lastoftype).</s> *(Edit: no it won't, last-of-type only takes element name in account.)* Use Javascript if that works for you, or add a `last` class in HTML.

@snaken: `:last-child` (CSS2 actually) is something very different: it selects elements which are last children of their parents. I.e.

```
<div>
  <a class="required">...</a>
  <a class="required">...</a>
  <a>...</a><!-- this is :last-child! -->
</div>
```

`required:last-child` will actually be empty here, because none of the `.required` elements are last children.